# Meteor: How can I embed template tags within other template tags?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

For example, I have an input field in my Meteor template:

```
{{> afQuickField name="mobile" options="auto" label="Your mobile number"}}
```

Then I start building an internationalised site, which means I need i18n the label text. Using `anti:i18n`, you can have internationalised text like this:

```
{{i18n "signup.form.mobile"}}
```

Now, how can I put this i18n-ed text into the previous template tag? I want something like

```
{{> afQuickField name="mobile" options="auto" label=(i18n 'signup.form.mobile')}}
```

but obviously it's wrong syntax.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe **almogdesign** approach helps you further...

https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/issues/483